# JavaFX: Toolbar with imagebuttons

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

How can i create a Toolbar like this:

LINK: http://s14.postimg.org/99095jk3l/image.png

I already created a toolbar with the correct background. My only problem are the buttons.
I dont know how to style the buttons to be transparant, and how to add the correct on hover and on click effects to match the background.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll be working with CSS.  You can set the background and border to `transparent`, then have a hover class for adding a semi-transparent border.  It would end up being something like this (Please note, you may have to make some tweaks still)

```
.button {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, transparent, transparent, transparent;
}

.button:hover{
    -fx-background-color: transparent, rgba(0,0,0,.1), rgba(0,0,0,.1), transparent;
}

.button:armed {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, rgba(0,0,0,.1), rgba(0,0,0,.1), rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

To apply the style sheet you'd use code similar to this:

```
toolbar.getStylesheets().add("filename.css");
```

There are lots of good references for this in the "Info" section of the "javafx-2" tag.  Here are a few that should prove helpful with this:

- [JavaFX 2 CSS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)
- [caspian.css for JavaFX 2.2](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt/raw-file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css) (The default style sheet)

Comment: What's the class name for toolbar?

Comment: According to http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#toolbar the class name for the toolbar is `tool-bar`